# How can i extract the meta property:"og:title" content with IMACROS

Tags: firefox, imacros

i need help to entract the content of meta property;"og:title" using the imacros extension for firefox.
For example for this code `<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />` shoud generate "My Page Title"...
I have tried all the ways to extract TXT, HTB... but i cant't do it...
Can anyone help me, give me an example of working codes please?

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=META ATTR=PROPERTY:"og:title" EXTRACT=HTM
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/.*content=\"(.*)\".*/, '$1').trim();")
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```